# Why is it not possible to execute compile-file in parallel?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I have a project that has a lot of files that are not managed by ASDF and are compiled manually. These files are completely independent and being able to compile them in parallel seemed like a way to reduce compilation time to me. My plan was to compile these files in parallel and then sequentially load produced FASL files. But after I parallelized compilation, I saw that there was literally zero performance improvement. Then I went to SBCL sources and found that [`compile-file` takes a world lock](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/5320db7fca9d110bd585ae8c26e9af2b8ca9f36e/src/compiler/main.lisp#L1718), which essentially sequentializes the compilation.

My question is, what's the reason that `compile-file` takes this lock? While loading FASLs in parallel could indeed lead to some race conditions, it seemed to me that compilation of Lisp files should be independent and parallelizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is accessible from the language.  You can do compile-time programming, have compiler macros etc.  Just as an illustration, there is `(eval-when (:compile) …)`.  You cannot rule out compile-time effects in general, and this would have to be thread safe everywhere.  I guess that the effort to make this robust is much bigger than one was willing to invest.

You might be able to start multiple Lisp images for parallel compilation, though.  You just need to handle the dependency graph while orchestrating that.

UPDATE: I just stumbled upon a conversation that seems to imply that SBCL is closer to getting rid of that lock than I thought: https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/mailman/message/36473674/